# Hibernate: detached of entities after commit()

Tags: java, hibernate, detach

I have recived the following error message in my code, althrough I never manually call the `detach()` command:

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: my.entity
```

My entities are persited using

```
try
        {
                entityManager.getTransaction().begin(); 
                entityManager.persist(item);
                entityManager.getTransaction().commit(); 
        }
        catch(final Exception e)
        {
               entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
               LOGGER.err("Error at persist.");
               throw new Exception();
        }
```

In the literature I found the hint that the `javax.persistence.EntityManager` automatically detached entities on `close()`, `EntityManager.getTransaction().commit()` and on serialisation. 
(see [here](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/img/jpa-state-transitions.png)). So I assume that every `item` is automitically detached after this operation. Correct?

I suspect that this is the root cause of my issues. I want to trigger the `detach() / merge()` only explicitly. Is there a posiblity to change the settings, so that `EntityManager.getTransaction().commit()` does NOT cause an `detach()`?

Comment: I guess you need to add the cascateType=DETACH in the entity you dont want to be affected with the changes in the parent entity

Comment: I dont think its good idea to do some changes on EntityManager.getTransaction().commit() to hide the issue, detach is required for proper rollback. By the way did you try saveOrUpdate in case of persist?

Comment: @ Cralfaro: Maybe I wasn't cear enough. My problem is that entities are detached althrough I have never called expicitly `detach()` in my code. So I have too much (and not too less) unwanted detached entities.

Comment: @ Parshant: I'm not targeting the change the source code of `EntityManager.getTransaction().commit()`. But maybe there are some accessable options to controll the behavour. I'll edit my question and try to make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entities get detached only when you close or clear the transaction not when you commit ?! ..

[Detach](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/detach)

> **The following operations clear the entire EntityManager's
> persistence context and detach all managed entity objects:**
>
> *Invocation of the close method, which closes an EntityManager.
>
> *Invocation of the clear method, which clears an EntityManager's
> persistence context.
>
> *Rolling back a transaction - either by invocation
> of rollback or by a commit failure.

Comment: Thanks Sagar, Seems that I have missinterpreted the docu from 'commit failure'  to 'on every commit'.  I'll investigate more in `saveOrUpdate()`

Comment: Could solve my Problem. Removing  the arguments from an `@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)` made the error disappear. Anyhow I'll investigate in more detail, why the entity was detached.